# How would you copy an ASP.Net project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, deployment, visual-sourcesafe

I have a .Net web application that I want to take a copy of and create a new application that can be worked on independently of the first - i.e. I want to branch the codebase.

What is the best way of going about this ?

TIA,

Tim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you've taken a local copy of the website, you can just copy and paste the web's root folder in explorer.  I'm not sure what kind of branching facilities source<strike>thief</strike>safe has, but you can add the new copy to your repository wherever you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - what will happen though to all the references in the solution/project file - can I just rename things ?

Comment: are you referring to references to non GAC assemblies?  if so, and any are broken, you should just be able to add them back in via the VS GUI

Answer (score 0):

Download VisualSVN Server, install it locally (takes 5 minutes) and create a repository for your project.  Then create a branch.

Comment: I would also recommend using VisualSVN over VSS but it looks like the question is being asked in a VSS context (see the tags)